# Is there way to video chat (two way) using sip in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Any one please help me in video calling service (like Skype). I am basically using SIP for implementation. 
So if there any link to related then please suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the project you are looking for on http://code.google.com/p/idoubs/

Comment: But Pandey jee how to implement that ?

Comment: You don't need to implement just compile the source code with the help of building guides on the page.

Comment: but where is link for download ?

Comment: Pandey G just check this link http://code.google.com/p/idoubs/downloads/detail?name=idoubs2.0.184-i386-10.6.dmg&can=2&q=

Comment: you need to checkout: svn checkout http://idoubs.googlecode.com/svn/ idoubs-read-only